# Efecto de fadeIn en el menú principal

Tags: javascript, jquery

En el momento de hacer click en los diferentes apartados del menú no consigo que aparezca el efecto de fadeIn con el texto que debería salir en cada uno de ellos (siempre se mantiene el texto del mismo apartado)

Éste es mi código:

```js
$('.textEnlaces').hide();
$('.textEnlaces:first').show();
var contenido_activo = $("#right h4 a href").click();
switch (contenido_activo) {
  case "tab2":
    $('.textEnlaces').hide();
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    break;

  case "#tab3":
    $('.textEnlaces:first').hidden();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    break;

  case "#tab4":
    $('.textEnlaces:first').hidden();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    break;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">
  <h4><a href="#tab1" class="cabecera"> La empresa </a> | <a href="#tab2" class="cabecera"> Metodología </a> | <a href="#tab3" class="cabecera">Historia</a> | <a href="#tab4" class="cabecera">Personal</a></h4>


  <div id="tab1" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 4</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código que compartes tiene varios errores:

1. No se asocia a ningún evento, con lo que se ejecutará siempre al principio de la página y nunca más (por eso sólo se ve el primero y no cambia a los otros). Para solucionarlo, asocia la acción al evento `click` de los enlaces.
2. El selector que usas para el `click` (`#right h4 a href`) no es válido. Esa fila completa no tiene sentido, de hecho. Lo que está haciendo ahora mismo es buscar la etiqueta (que no atributo) `href` y pulsándola (pero como no existe, no ocurre nada). Cuando asocies la acción al evento `click` (punto 1), podrás leer el atributo `href` del enlace pulsado usando `attr("href")`.
3. En el `switch...case`, el `case` para el `tab2` es incorrecto porque le falta un `#` al principio (que sí llevan los otros).
4. No has definido un caso para el `#tab1`. Tal y como está ahora, el `tab1` siempre se mostrará independientemente del enlace que se pulse.
5. No existe el método `hidden()` en jQuery, parece que quieres usar `hide()` como ya se hace para el `#tab2`.
6. `this` no es lo que crees que es. Estás poniendo `$(this).addClass(...)` o `$(this).fadeIn()`... pero, ¿qué es `this` en el contexto que lo estás usando? Porque quieres que sea el `tab` con el que operas, pero en realidad es el enlace que se pulsó (o el documento), pero no el tab.
7. Cuando pulsas en los enlaces para tab3 y tab4, sólo se oculta el primer tab, pero si la pestaña activa no era la primera, entonces no se oculta nada y se ven dos pestañas abiertas al mismo tiempo. Cámbialo para que se oculten siempre todas las pestañas.

Esos son algunos cambios para que funcione:

```js
$('.textEnlaces').hide();
$('.textEnlaces:first').show();
  
$("#right h4 a").on("click", function() {
  
  var contenido_activo = $(this).attr("href");

  switch (contenido_activo) {
   
      case "#tab1":
      $('.textEnlaces').hide();
      $(contenido_activo).fadeIn(1000);
      break;
      
    case "#tab2":
      $('.textEnlaces').hide();
      $(contenido_activo).fadeIn(1000);
      break;

    case "#tab3":
      $('.textEnlaces').hide();
      $(contenido_activo).addClass('active');
      $(contenido_activo).fadeIn(1000);
      break;

    case "#tab4":
      $('.textEnlaces').hide();
      $(contenido_activo).addClass('active');
      $(contenido_activo).fadeIn(1000);
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">
  <h4><a href="#tab1" class="cabecera"> La empresa </a> | <a href="#tab2" class="cabecera"> Metodología </a> | <a href="#tab3" class="cabecera">Historia</a> | <a href="#tab4" class="cabecera">Personal</a></h4>


  <div id="tab1" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 4</p>
  </div>
```

Ahora, el código aún puede mejorarse:

- Añades la clase `.activo` pero no la quitas en ningún sitio, por lo que llegará un momento en el que todos los tab tengan esa clase, perdiendo su utilidad.
- El código se repite mucho, si te fijas, se podría simplificar ahorrándote el `switch...case` y aplicando el mismo código a todos los tabs independientemente del enlace que se pulsó ([lee sobre DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas)).
- Puedes concatenar acciones para ahorrarte selecciones.

Y con esos cambios:

```js
$('.textEnlaces').hide();
$('.textEnlaces:first').show();
  
$("#right h4 a").on("click", function() {
  var contenido_activo = $(this).attr("href");
  $('.textEnlaces').hide().removeClass("active");
  $(contenido_activo).fadeIn(1000).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">
  <h4><a href="#tab1" class="cabecera"> La empresa </a> | <a href="#tab2" class="cabecera"> Metodología </a> | <a href="#tab3" class="cabecera">Historia</a> | <a href="#tab4" class="cabecera">Personal</a></h4>


  <div id="tab1" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="textEnlaces">
    <p>texto 4</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: El código funciona (lo puedes ver arriba). Si tienes los script en el `head` entonces debes encapsularlos en un `$(document).ready` para asegurarte que se ejecutan cuando la página (y los elementos a los que el script afecta) se hayan cargado correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

¿intentaste un encadenamiento? Algo como esto.

```
switch (contenido_activo) {
  case "tab2":
    $('.textEnlaces').hide().fadeIn(1000);
    break;

  case "#tab3":
    $('.textEnlaces:first').hide().addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
    break;

  case "#tab4":
    $('.textEnlaces:first').hide.addClass('active').fadeIn(1000);
    break;
}
```

Quizas no te esta reconociendo los selectores , por otro lado me parece que la función es hide() y no hidden().

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar, saludos.